# UPDATE query in MySQL on large table

Tags: mysql, table-locking, large-data

I have a MySQL database with 21M records and I'm trying to do an update on about 1M records but the query fails with `ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size.`

Is it possible to update the table without acquiring locks?

I don't have access to change MySQL configuration parameters like `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Is there a different way to achieve the same?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

1. I've tried it in batches of 5000, it works a few times, but I get the same error
2. I've tried LOCK TABLES to lock the entire table and still it doesn't work.

Comment: http://rackerhacker.com/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/

Comment: only do it in chunks like faisal said

Comment: What a stupid limitation. Anyone know of a work around? I guess use MyISAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the limit clause to do the updates in batches.

Comment: I've tried it in batches of 5000, it works a few times, but I get the same error

Comment: Then perhaps try tinier chunks? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try locking at table level rather than row level. Use `LOCK TABLES MyTable WRITE`. This might solve the problem. No guarantees though! Don't forget to unlock the tables either!